# How can i make my batch file search for a file and run it?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, exe

So far, i have tried to make a batch file see if a file is there, and if yes, execute it. It works with default Microsoft programs (Word,Powerpoint,Windows Media Player...), but whenever i try to do it with an external program (I took Inkscape as i could have taken CoD, .exe file), it says that the command syntax is wrong. Here's my code:

```
if %prog% equ ink ( 
if exist C:>inkscape (
    start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe"
) else (
    rem Sorry
)
)
```

Can you tell me what's wrong, and please give a script example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if %prog% equ ink ( 
    if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" ( 
        start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" 
    ) else ( 
        rem Sorry 
    ) 
)
```

Syntax is `if exist filename` - not `if exist foldername`

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the folder like this:

```
if %prog% equ ink ( 
    if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\" ( 
        start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" 
    ) else ( 
        rem Sorry 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have to check if the file itself exists, because the folder may exist, but the file is maybe deleted :)